# Frequency Capping in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Is there a way I can cap the no. of emails sent out of a Journey? I don't want to send more than two emails to a subscriber from any journey.

Answer (score 3):

Although the ask is not very clear(like how many emails are there in your journey, do you want contacts to exit when they have already received 2 emails or you want users to continue the journey but not receive emails?).

But you can try to follow this method if it applies to your use case:

1) The data extension on which the journey is running, add a new column 'numberOfEmails' to it.

2) In your journey, after every email activity, add an 'Update Contact' activity which updates this field of your Data Extension. So, for instance, your subscriber has already received 2 emails from this journey, after the second email the field in this DE will be updated to two.

3) Now set a Goal to your journey with an exit criteria that if this particular field('numberOfEmails') reaches a value 2, contact exits the journey.

Please refer this link to define the Goal: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_define_goal.htm&type=5